# storing string that has unicode character in it

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, unicode, doctrine-orm

I have a string that has the following content:

```
  \ud83c\udf80NEW STUFF \u0026 SECOND STUFF\n\ud83d\udcf1Sms\/ Kik : 085738566676 \/ veinshop\n\u26d4 All item exclude ongkir\n\u2708Shipping mon-fri\n\ud83d\udcb0BCA only\n\ud83d\ude90JNE\n\ud83c\udfe1 Denpasar-bali
```

I wanted to store this in my MySQL database however it always gives me empty. I am using doctrine2 ORM as an interface to the database. Here's the entity with the string property:

```
class Shop
{

 /**
     *
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="bio", type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $bio;

 /**
     * Set bio
     *
     * @param string $bio
     * @return InstagramShop
     */
    public function setBio($bio)
    {
        $this->bio = $bio;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bio
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getBio()
    {
        return $this->bio;
    }
}
```

When I set this Shop entity with the bio and call persist on the entity. The stored value is NULL. I've set my table collation to `utf8mb4` and my charset in dbo to `utf8mb4`

Comment: Set table collation and  connection collation to utf8mb4

Comment: @Mihai how do I set the connection collation?

Comment: After you connect add 
sql_query('SET NAMES utf8mb4');

EDIT: in DBO:
DBO::query('SET NAMES utf8mb4');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have a config that looks something like this:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                dbname: %database_name%
                ...
                charset: utf8mb4
```

Make sure `charset` is set to `utf8mb4`.  This is your connection collation.